# .size() of a nested LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a nested LinkedList that I need to run through a loop and need the .size() of the nested list. How can I access this nested list? The outer list only has 1 element and that element has the number of elements I need to run the for loop.

> ```
> LinkedList<LinkedList<Plan>> eligiblePlansList = new LinkedList<>();
> LinkedList<String> planNames = new LinkedList<>();
> String [] arr;
>
> /**
>  * Creates new form ComparePlansGUI
>  */
> public ComparePlansGUI() {
>     initComponents();
> }
>
> public ComparePlansGUI(HealthCare hc, Customer c){       
>     this.hc = hc;
>
>     eligiblePlansList.add(p.eligiblePlans(c, hc.getPlans()));
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < eligiblePlansList.size(); i++){
>         planNames.add(i, eligiblePlansList.get(i).get(i).planName); 
>     }
>
>     arr = planNames.toArray(new String[planNames.size()]);
>
>     planNames.clear();
>
>     initComponents();
> }
> ```

Comment: eligiblePlansList.get(i).size() will do

Comment: It is convention to accept an answer if any of them helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eligiblePlansList.get(0).size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
eligiblePlansList.get(0).size()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add additional loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < eligiblePlansList.size(); i++) {
    LinkedList<Plan> planList = eligiblePlansList.get(i); // current list

    for (int j = 0; i < planList.size(); i++) {
        Plan plan = planList.get(j); // current plan
        planNames.add(i, plan.planName); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for(Linkedlist item:plans)

for(plan p:item)